How to list npm dependencies without deduping
I am using the following command to generate dependency list -
npm ls --production --depth=1000 --long=true --legacy-building=true

There are packages that show 'deduped'
To avoid this, I tried using --legacy-building=true but that didn't help.
I need all dependencies to be listed including duplicates.
How to generate the dependency list without 'deduping'?
